# WordPress option page not showing submitting value

Tags: php, wordpress

I have to create an option page using array in my wordpress theme. after submitting all fill up information removed while i am using

> var_dump( $this->options)  show blank array(){}

I want when submitting option page form submit information show in the input box and i will `get_option` value in some variable so that i have to display the information in my theme.

```
   <?php 
class MySettingsPage
{
    private $options;
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'bguru_register_options_page' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'bguru_register_settings' ) );
    }

    public function bguru_register_options_page()
    {
        // This page will be under "Settings"
        add_theme_page('Business Guru Options',
                'Theme Customizer',
                'edit_theme_options',
                'bguru-options',
                array( $this, 'bguru_options_page')
        );
    }

    public function bguru_options_page()
    {

        // Set class property
          $bguru_logo = is_array( get_option( 'bguru_logo' ) ) ? get_option( 'bguru_logo' ) : array();

         $bguru_vimeo = is_array( get_option( 'bguru_vimeo' ) ) ? get_option( 'bguru_vimeo' ) : array();

          $this->options = array_merge( $bguru_logo, $bguru_vimeo);

var_dump($this->options);
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <?php screen_icon(); ?>
            <h1>Business Guru Options</h1>
            <form method="post" action="options.php">
                <?php
                // This prints out all hidden setting fields
                settings_fields( 'defaultbg' );
                do_settings_sections( 'defaultbg' );
                submit_button();
                ?>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    public function bguru_register_settings()
    {
        register_setting('defaultbg','bguru_logo',  array( $this, 'sanitize' ) );
        register_setting('defaultbg', 'bguru_vimeo',  array( $this, 'sanitize' ));
        add_settings_section(
                'setting_section_id', // ID
                'General',
                array( $this, 'print_section_info' ), // Callback
                'defaultbg' // Page

        );

        add_settings_field(
                'bguru_logo', // ID
                'Logo', // Title
                array($this,'logo_callback' ), // Callback
                'defaultbg', // Page
                'setting_section_id' // Section
        );

        add_settings_field(
                'bguru_vimeo', // ID
                'Vimeo', // Vimeo
                array( $this, 'socialv_callback' ), // Callback
                'defaultbg', // Page
                'setting_section_id' // Section
        );
    }

    public function sanitize( $input )
    {
        $new_input = array();

        if( isset( $input['bguru_logo'] ) )
            $new_input['bguru_logo'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['bguru_logo'] );

        if( isset( $input['bguru_vimeo'] ) )
            $new_input['bguru_vimeo'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['bguru_vimeo'] );

        return $new_input;
    }
    public function print_section_info()
    {
        print 'Enter your settings below:';
    }

    public function logo_callback()
    {
        printf('<input type="text" id="bguru_logo"  size="50" name="bguru_logo" value="%s" />',
                isset( $this->options['bguru_logo'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->options['bguru_logo']) : ''
        );
    }

    public function socialv_callback()
    {
        printf('<input type="text" id="bguru_vimeo"  size="50" name="bguru_vimeo" value="%s" />',
                isset( $this->options['bguru_vimeo'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->options['bguru_vimeo']) : ''
        );
    }
}
if( is_admin() )
    $my_settings_page = new MySettingsPage();
```

Comment: Could you please try `var_dump(get_option( 'bguru_logo' ));` in first line inside the function `bguru_options_page`?

Comment: i try `var_dump(get_option( 'bguru_logo' ));` it shows array(0) { } and the notice is removed please see my updated code still it show blank array(){}

Comment: You have var dumped `$this->options`, I said `get_option( 'bguru_logo' )`? Could you please try that

Comment: even i tried var_dump(get_option( 'bguru_logo' )); still it shows the same blank array array(0) { }

Comment: friends suggest some solutions how to get value from input field